# Not able to understand Refresh() method to refresh LINQ-to-SQL DataContext.

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have checked other codes online but I am not able to understand the parameters of refresh() method to refresh my linq-to-sql data context.

I am deleting the data of table B so that I can then delete data of table A. And then I want to update my Gridview so that it now shows the data of table B with required record deleted.

```
public static void DeleteCategory(int id)
    {
        var result = from a in adb.Artifacts                 //adb is my data context visible to every code.
                     where a.CatgId == id
                     select new { artid = a.ArtId};

        var count = result.Count();
        int counter = 0;




            if (count > 0)
            {
                foreach (var r in result)
                {

                    MyArtifact.DeleteByKey(r.artid);
                    count--;
                    counter = 1;
                }
            }
            if (counter==0)
            {
                MyCategories.DeleteByKey(id);        
            }
```

**// I should use the refresh() method here but I am not able to understand the parameters RefreshMode and Entity!!! Can some one please explain me these two!!**
}

Thank You

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dinesh.kulkarni/archive/2008/05/23/linq-to-sql-tips-6-how-to-refresh-given-datacontext-won-t-stomp-on-your-objects.aspx

Comment: Hey tim, 
I have checked that blog! But I am not able to identify what should I use for the parameter for refresh() for my application. It says entity and refreshmode. 

Thanks

Comment: I have tried writing adb.Refresh(RefreshMode.OverwriteCurrentValues, Artifact); But doing this, I get a error 'AdlibCoreModel.Artifact' is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable'

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you need to use refresh but to change the way you delete. If you delete using the context it should not need to be refereshed.

I would alter the entity mapping cascade settings the when you delete a category it will delete the artifacts automatically

Comment: Hey Andy,
I am using DeleteOnSubmit() using LINQ to delete it...I understand the mapping cascade settings..But I want to know the refresh() as I will be using while updating or inserting in future...

Comment: Yeah I can..I want to but I am not getting the second parameter for it....it shows me a error if u can read my above comments...

Comment: Well microsofts example is  context.Refresh(RefreshMode.ClientWins, orders); I would try  context.Refresh(RefreshMode.ClientWins, result);

Comment: Hi Andy, ur code doesn't help for the work..Is thik fine to Create an object of data context each time I query?? Will this be a problem because my database will carry about 50-60K records overall...??